# Can I use local and hosted agents for the same build

Tags: build, continuous-integration, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

I have Hosted agent in the Hosted queue and I also installed local agent in the Default queue. Can I use them for the same build configuration to have builds running in parallel (for different branches/versions/etc)?

Answer (score 1):

The same build can’t be run in local and hosted agent. You can queue multiple build with different build agent. Another build can be triggered during current build by calling [Queue a build](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/build/builds#queue-a-build) rest api.

Answer (score 0):

A build definition can only be configured against one Agent Queue, so it is not possible currently to use both Hosted as well as Default agent queue for a single build definition.

You can instead buy more Hosted Pipelines that will allow you to run more builds on Hosted agents in parallel or you can configure more local agents.

Comment: I understand the current state of play and my question was mainly if it is possible to make a workaround.

Comment: You can clone your build and trigger them based on checked-in or pushed branch it won't be a single build definition but it think it will solve your problem, But If you need to use 2 or more agents in your release you can simply do it with adding a Phase.